WinForms: Communicate data from a user control to its parent form
I have a form and a user control on it. And I try to communicate data from the user control to the form.
When the user interacts with the user control, a user control's variable value is changed and an event is raised to which the form is listening. I want the form to display the current value of this variable in a label.
I implemented an event, a delegate and the event handler for the form and it works as long as the form displays the current value in a message box.
But when I want it to be displayed in a label on the form it doesn't work, because the event handler is static and when I try to apply the new value to the label, there is no reference to it inside the handler.
An alternative approach may be to transmit the value in the first place through the event - I guess this would even be better, because then the variable could be implemented as private but I have no idea how to load a variable on the event.
Can anybody help me here? I never worked with self-written events before and I don't know how to continue.
This is the form:
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Delegate
        public delegate void MyUserControlEventHandler(MyUserControl sender);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // EventHandler
        public static void Form1_ListenToChanges(MyUserControl sender)
        {             
            MessageBox.Show("Value was changed. Current value: " + sender.value.ToString());
            //The following will not work:
            //label1.Text = sender.value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

and this is the user control:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static Events.Form1;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public int value;

        // Event
        public event MyUserControlEventHandler Value_Change;
        
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Value_Change += new MyUserControlEventHandler(Form1_ListenToChanges);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value++;
            // Raise event
            if(Value_Change != null) Value_Change(this);
        }
    }
}


Why don't you use the standard event handler signature (object sender EventArgs e); yeah,  it's not needed, but it's jarring to the eyes. Why did you make your event handler static. Your problem is because it is static. Do you have acreason you're doing it this way?

The event handler shouldn't be static.
public void Form1_ListenToChanges(MyUserControl sender)

And the event subscription should be effected in the Form1 class.
public Form1()
{
    // ...
    this.myUserControl.Value_Change += this.Form1_ListenToChanges;
}

(Form1 has a MyUserControl, right? The code snippet above assumes that it does and that it is this.myUserControl.)
(You can then make the event handler private.)
private void Form1_ListenToChanges(MyUserControl sender)


When I remove the static clause from the event handler, it becomes unavailable in the User Control. I think this is why I made it static.  And when I move the event subscription into the form, MyUserControlEventHandler will become unavailable in the User Control too.  I think this is where the using static Events.Form1; in MyUserControl came in: it is just a "potential fix" proposed by Visual Studio.  I have to admit that my knowledge is not sufficient to understand what's behind it.

The event handler shouldn't be available in the User Control. Trying to post changes here in this comment but the max comment length is too short. Will post another answer hopefully clarifying things...

Thank you Jeremy for clarification! The following works: 1. I don't need to initialize the user control in the Form1.cs file. Instead I have a private MyUserControl myUserControl; in the Form1.Designer.cs file. 2. Delegate and event are in MyUserControl.cs: public delegate void MyUserControlEventHandler(MyUserControl sender); public event MyUserControlEventHandler Value_Change; 3. And the event handler is in Form1.cs: this.myUserControl.Value_Change += this.Form1_ListenToChanges; Now nothing is static anymore, so label1.Text = sender.value.ToString(); works in the handler too.

Your question is about how to Communicate data from a user control to its parent form.
The comment and previous answer do a good job explaining why the static event handler works only for calling static methods like MessageBox.Show(). I'd like to more broadly answer how a user control might communicate with its parent, and hopefully set you up to win in this endeavor by doing it in a more standard, supportable and scalable way. A strategy that is often used is to have the user control send a PropertyChanged notification whenever any of its  properties changes. Since the sender argument identifies which user control has changed, and the e.PropertyName argument identifies the specific property, all the information required to act on the event is available without having to write a separate event for each and every property that you might add. As a minimal example, here's a UserControl set up with this pattern.

User Control that Notifies when Property Changes

public partial class UserControlWithNotify : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControlWithNotify()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Bind the properties to the control instances.
        textBox.KeyDown += TextBox_Commit;      // For example, respond to the Enter key
        textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_Commit;    // For example, respond to the Tab key
        numericUpDown.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, nameof(NumericValue), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
    private void TextBox_Commit(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e is KeyEventArgs eKey && eKey.KeyData != Keys.Enter) return;
        TextValue = textBox.Text;
    }
    public int NumericValue
    {
        get => _numericValue;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_numericValue, value))
            {
                _numericValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    int _numericValue = default;

    public string TextValue
    {
        get => _textValue;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_textValue, value))
            {
                _textValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _textValue = string.Empty;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}


Setting the Parent up to Listen
On this example form, two instances of UserControlWithNotify that are added e.g. in the Designer will be present in the Controls collection of the parent, and this provides a good way to attach the PropertyChanged event.

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (UserControlWithNotify userControlWithNotify in this.Controls.OfType<UserControlWithNotify>())
        {
            userControlWithNotify.PropertyChanged += AnyUserControlWithNotify_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void AnyUserControlWithNotify_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is UserControlWithNotify userControlWithNotify)
        {
            richTextBox.Clear();
            richTextBox.AppendText("Control Name: ", Color.Blue, style: FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox.AppendText(userControlWithNotify.Name, newLine: true);
            richTextBox.AppendText("Property Name: ", Color.Blue, style: FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox.AppendText(e.PropertyName, newLine: true);
            richTextBox.AppendText("New Value: ", Color.Blue, style: FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox.AppendText(
                $"{typeof(UserControlWithNotify)
                .GetProperty(e.PropertyName)
                .GetValue(userControlWithNotify)}", newLine: true);
        }
    }
}
static class Extensions
{
    public static void AppendText(
        this RichTextBox textBox,
        string text,
        Color? color = null,
        FontStyle? style = FontStyle.Regular,
        bool newLine = false)
    {
        var colorB4 = textBox.SelectionColor;
        var fontB4 = textBox.SelectionFont;
        if (color.HasValue) textBox.SelectionColor = color.Value;
        if (style.HasValue) textBox.SelectionFont = new Font(textBox.SelectionFont, style.Value);
        textBox.AppendText(text);
        if(newLine) textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        textBox.SelectionColor = colorB4;
        textBox.SelectionFont = fontB4;
    }
}


To be clear: The static event handler is only working for showing the message box. But I want to have something that updates the label on the form and that's what is not working.
As I commented above to @jeremydalmer's comment, it is not possible to get rid of the static definitions so far - at least with the approach I am pursuing.  Yours seems much more complicated but I will try to understand it.  That will take a bit more time, because I haven't used interfaces so far (except IEnumerable and I IComparer ... which are far easier to understand).

Ah, yes, of course. I went ahead and tweaked the answer a little bit to correct the misstatement and to give an example of updating a label. Feel free to clone this sample if it would help.

Thank you IV for the great sample! I just cloned it and will play around with it! I appreciate your support a lot!

Here are changes that will work if you incorporate them into your full code. I also suggest moving the delegate to the user control class. There are other changes you should consider. See IV's answer. These are just small changes to get it working.
THE FORM:
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.myUserControl.Value_Change += this.Form1_ListenToChanges;
        }

        // EventHandler
        private void Form1_ListenToChanges(MyUserControl sender)
        {             
            MessageBox.Show("Value was changed. Current value: " + sender.value.ToString());
            //The following will not work:
            //label1.Text = sender.value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

THE USER CONTROL:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public int value;

        public delegate void MyUserControlEventHandler(MyUserControl sender);

        // Event
        public event MyUserControlEventHandler Value_Change;
        
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value++;
            // Raise event
            if(Value_Change != null) Value_Change(this);
        }
    }
}


after @Jeremy Dalmer helped me to overcome the problem with the static event handler and clarified in which class the event, delegate and eventHandler had to go, it was only a small step to follow @Flydog57's advice to use the standard event signature (object sender EventArgs e).
For sake of simplicity I put the definition of the event argument class into the same file as the form. I think it is clear now, how to put even more data load on it.
Finally it is possible to define the value variable as private in the user control.
The result corresponds now to my current level of programming skills. It may be helpful for other newbies like me who search for basic examples for event handling using Winforms.
Full code for the form and the event argument:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.myUserControl.Value_Change += this.Form1_ListenToChanges;
        }

        // EventHandler
        public void Form1_ListenToChanges(MyUserControl sender, ListenToChangesEventArgs e)
        {             
            //The following will work now:
            label1.Text = e.Count.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class ListenToChangesEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int _Count;
        public int Count
        {
            get { return _Count; }
        }
        public ListenToChangesEventArgs(int count)
        {
            _Count = count;
        }
    }
}

Full code for the user control:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Events
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private int value;

        // Delegate
        public delegate void MyUserControlEventHandler(MyUserControl sender, ListenToChangesEventArgs e);

        // Event
        public event MyUserControlEventHandler Value_Change;

        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value++;
            // Raise event
            if (Value_Change != null) Value_Change(this, new ListenToChangesEventArgs(value));
        }
    }
} 

